# How to setup CI/CD pipelines on Azure devops for Hybris (SAP commerce cloud, CCv2)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to setup Azure CICD pipelines for hybris and and not clear on the entire process.

The pipelines are not configured with hybris setup and can't authenticate hybris custom packages with azure pipelines hosted build agents.

Created Windows build agent in Agent pools. My understanding is that, now it is require an instance to configure the build agent.

(so far these steps are just for the CI configuration)

Is this the right approach?  Has anyone configured this kind of setup?

Comment: This [blog](https://sapbazar.com/articles/item/3009-build-a-cicd-pipeline-with-azure-devops-for-sap-hana-xsa-part-2) introduces Build A CI/CD Pipeline with Azure DevOps for SAP HANA XSA, does it help.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is Kaushik's answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

With CCv2 ,CI & CD needs to be differentiated. CI will be completely in one's control whereas CCv2 will be with SAP . Through Azure Devops, you can set the CI pipeline.

1. Configure an agent (can be windows / Linux)
2. Use a VM to act as a build server and install necessary tools / software
   2.1 You will need to extract Hybris within this
   2.2 Checkout code from your repository under custom folder (Using Azure Devops)
   2.3 Compile Hybris (Using ANT task in Azure Devops)
   2.4 Run Junit Targets and publish results
   2.5 If you have a static code analyser configure it with your respective ANT scripts
   2.6 Run your Code analyser task in ANT to publish results
   2.7 Based on your threshold set (for 2.5 & 2.6) , you can make your build to pass / fail
   2.8 Based on the result of 2.7 , you can create an artefact and either store it in a cloud repo like Nexus / store it in your VM , the former is better.
   2.9 Deploy the code in VM and run your automated tests
   2.10 If the results are satisfactory , then merge the code to a release branch
   2.11 This completes the CI process
3. Use the release branch , to check out the code and use the CCv2 rest APIs (https://help.sap.com/viewer/452dcbb0e00f47e88a69cdaeb87a925d/v1905/en-US/9d7854f5297a400e9c8ce3a2819d3c82.html) to build and deploy from Azure Devops.

In the case of multiple branches , the process described above (Section 2)  will have to be tailored according to your custom needs